# Powershell I want to prepend a "# " down to the first blank line

Tags: powershell

Starting with this...

```
This is the test
This is the test
This is the test 

This is the test 

This is the test
```

How do I add "#" to the front of each line down to the blank line

```
# This is the test
# This is the test
# This is the test 

This is the test 

This is the test
```

This is my current code which puts "# " in front of every line --

```
$Lines = Get-Content -path C:\Users\mike\Downloads\test1.txt
$OutputPath = "C:\Users\mike\Downloads\test2.txt"
foreach ($Line in $Lines) {$Line = $Line.Insert(0,'# ') | Out-File $OutputPath -Append }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something that identifies when a blank line is encountered. I am confident that this could be done more efficiently, but here is a crude example.

```
$Lines = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\mike\Downloads\test1.txt
$OutputPath = "C:\Users\mike\Downloads\test2.txt"
$BlankHit = $false
foreach ($Line in $Lines) {
    if ($Line -match '^\s*$') { $BlankHit = $true }
    if ($BlankHit) {
        $OutLine = $Line
    } else {
        $OutLine = '# ' + $Line
    }
    $OutLine | Out-File $OutputPath -Append
 }
```

Comment: works great!  And I got to learn a little bit about if/else statements in powershell - thank you!